# Excel 2013 selecting a row, but only if value is not zero

Tags: excel, vba

My problem might be really simple, but can't seem to find the answer anywhere.
I'am really a noob to Macro, this is my first attempt to it.
Recorded the marco with all the steps of what I would need to do with an excel,  but in one step excel would only need to select cells where the value is greater than zero.

But due to obvious reasons it is looking like this now:

```
Range("P3:P114").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("E101").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=3
```

This will only work in the scenario where the P has positive values until like 114.

Any help would be apprechiated

Comment: Just to get your question right, what you want to do is select some Cells in column **P** depending on the value in the Cells in this column (>0), right? Second question, do you also want to copy & paste this selection to some other place, or is it really just selecting the cells? Also is the number of rows in column **P** fix or variable?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding about your question is right, then try using this code.

```
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long
r = 50
For c = r To 1 Step -1
If Cells(c, 1) = 0 Then
Rows(c).Select
End If
Next
```